# htaccess browser caching not working : Laravel

Tags: php, .htaccess, caching, laravel-5

I have checked on google page speed which is showing 48/100 and after implementing cache in htaccess, page speed is same.Please tell if i need to add something else in this file or other files to implement cache.

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
        <FilesMatch "\\.(js|css|woff|woff2)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
        </FilesMatch>

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

for google insights validate your cache you need include the images to cache too

example:

```
# weekend cache

<FilesMatch ".(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>


<FilesMatch ".(xml|txt|css|js)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, proxy-revalidate"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```